# Credentials file not read Rails 6.1 on Amazon Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently upgraded my `Rails6.0` app to `Rails6.1` and I was not using a feature of rails called credentials. So I decided to make it work.

My App has 3 environments:

1. development
2. staging
3. production

to use credentials feature, I am using below commands:

For development: `EDITOR="vscode --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment development`

For staging: `EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment staging`

For production: `EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment production`

here's the sample of yml

```
aws:
  s3_access_key: XXXXXXXXX
  s3_secret: xxxxxxxx
  s3_bucket_name: xxxxxx
```

and here's my `config/environments/staging.rb`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_protocol: :https,
  preserve_files: true,
  s3_region: 's3_region',
  url: ':s3_alias_url',
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:s3_bucket_name],
    access_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:s3_access_key],
    secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:s3_secret]
  }
}
```

Since my app is hosted on AWS ElasticBeanstalk so after making all the changes when I am deploying my rails application, the deployment fails with this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/var/app/ondeck/config/environments/staging.rb:51:in `block in <main>'
```

My lineNo#51 points to this `Rails.application.credentials.aws[:s3_bucket_name]`

I have also tried the plain way - i.e. not applying / adding the attributes in nested way but the problem stays the same.

It is clear that credentials file is not loading.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you copy your master key(config/master.key) to server? By default it in .gitignore.
You can symlink this file to a shared folder in the server filesystem for easy deployment.

Comment: hello @alex-govorov I do not have config/master.key present. Instead I do have config/environments/development.key, config/environments/staging.key and config/environments/production.key
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do I have to create this file and set values like this: `RAILS_STAGING_KEY=cat config/credentials/staging.key`

Comment: it's neither in .gitignore all I can see this is:

`/config/credentials/development.key`
`/config/credentials/test.key`
`/config/credentials/staging.key`
`/config/credentials/production.key`

Comment: Oh sure you don't have config/master.key because you create environment specific keys. So yes, you moving in right direction.

Example for heroku:
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/credentials/production.key`

Comment: The solution of adding RAILS MASTER KEY worked for me. Accepted your answer.